# How do I allow for only one checkbox to be checked in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Please reference my spreadsheet for help answering this question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rNH-TZFa51EL5CwcSGTj5TR-x9V46ajBFyXbTeXYqBI/edit?usp=sharing

I have created a Gooogle Sheet for my customers to select which features they want to purchase for a package deal. I figured out how to sum the prices for a total, but I am having trouble figuring out how only to allow customers to select only a certain number of boxes per SECTION so they won't get overcharged for things they do not need/select more boxes than they should.

Each package comes with a certain number of items you can get from a particular section of the sheet. For example, the base package allows for ONE out of 7 additional pages, while the advanced package allows for 4 out of 7 additional pages.

Obviously, I do not want the customer to select SIX additional pages if they want the base package because they only pay for ONE when selecting the base package. I need the rest of the additional page boxes to become deactivated if they choose the base package, then choose one addition page, or if they select the advanced package and select four additional pages, and so on.

The same thing goes with the forms. The advanced package only lets you select two interactive forms, so I do not want them to have the option of choosing more than two boxes. This option should ONLY be allowed if they have selected the premium package deal.

Again, as you can see, #4, for the marketing programs, of course, customers won't need both the Market Starter AND the Market Pro; they need only to select ONE of these options. I would like the ability to deactivate one box if they choose the other.

I have read a lot of the other articles referring to OnEdit, but I have no idea what that is, nor do I know anything about code! I am quite surprised that I got as far as I did on this sheet. I hope my question was thorough, but if not, feel free to ask any questions. Please help!!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand about your issue. Can I ask you about it? And also, if you can show your current script and the issue of it, I think that it will help users think of the issue and solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Validation instead.

Unfortunately Sheets doesn't have [radio buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio) for the Sheets interface, but Data Validation is pretty much the same. You can follow the steps to create it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code which runs onEdit and works as if you have radio buttons:

**Code:**

```
  function onEdit(evt) {

  var range = evt.range;
  var val = range.getValue();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  // -------------------------------------
  // Only 1 checkbox per row can be ticked ---
  // i=6  because we start at Column F, then i<9 because we stop at H (Col 8)


  for(var i = 6;i<9;i++){
    if(i == col) continue;

    // We check that we are on the right row (26) and columns (6,7,8)

    if (row == 26 && col == 6 || col == 7 || col == 8){

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,i).setValue('FALSE');    
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**:

Sometimes keeping things simple, is much better than trying to do something a little bit more sophisticated.

You could have (by yourself) used a simple drop-down menu with the 3 packages: I've added a sheet illustrating this with the formula.

[image]